# Using if statement in subquery ORM Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get two parameters in my function as `mobile` and `tel`.
If they aren't null, I want to search between my customers where it has a relation with my lead.

This is my query:

```php
$lead = $this->query()
    ->with([
        'customer' => function ($query) use ($mobile, $tel) {
            $query->when($mobile != '', function ($query) use ($mobile) {
                return $query->where('mobile','=', $mobile);
            });

            $query->when($tel != '', function ($query) use ($tel) {
                return $query->where('tel','=', $tel);
            });
        },

    ])
    ->first();
```

However, it returns the wrong result.

Comment: And what is the issue? What does "it returns the wrong result" mean? What are you getting back that it should not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if` statements to check if `$mobile` and `$tel` are not null and then directly apply the where clauses to the $query.

```
$lead = $this->query()->with('customer');

if ($mobile !== null || $tel !== null) {
    $lead->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($mobile, $tel) {
        if ($mobile !== null) {
            $query->where('mobile', $mobile);
        }

        if ($tel !== null) {
            $query->where('tel', $tel);
        }
    });
}

$lead = $lead->first();
```

Comment: It always returns  first my lead. I don't know where is my wrong.

Comment: Use get() instead of first()?

Comment: it returns all my records (my leads.).

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do this operation. It all depends on the query model that we're using it.

**Option 1:**

```
$lead = $this->query()
    ->with([
        'customer' => function ($query) use ($mobile, $tel) {
            $query->when($mobile != null, function ($q) use ($mobile) {
                return $q->where('mobile', $mobile);
            });

            $query->when($tel != null, function ($q) use ($tel) {
                return $q->where('tel', $tel);
            });
        },
    ])
    ->first();
```

Here we check the condition in one query model if the `mobile` is not empty then check the condition as well if `tel` is not empty then check the condition and return the results.

**Option 2:**

```
$leadQuery = $this->query()->with(['customer']);

if ($mobile !== null) {
    $leadQuery->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($mobile) {
        $query->where('mobile', $mobile);
    });
}

if ($tel !== null) {
    $leadQuery->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($tel) {
        $query->where('tel', $tel);
    });
}

$lead = $leadQuery->first();
```

This one is also a good query where we can check our multiple conditions one by one with the `query` model. We do the operations multiple times and get `results`.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian If you found any error then share it with me. I checked this code and it's working fine.